# Ctrl-A and Ctrl-X seemed to be switched sometimes!

Tags: key-bindings

Occasionally, I will press `Ctrl-x` and `Ctrl-a` to increment/decrement the highlighted number, and the opposite operation will happen.

This usually happens when I'm working with with registers (`q`).  Could I possibly be setting up some sort of alias between the two commands?  How do I fix it besides opening/closing vim?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nevermind, the number I was incrementing was in a date time (like `2015-08-07`) and I think vim was interpreting it as a negative integer.

D'oh.

Comment: [vim-speeddating](https://github.com/tpope/vim-speeddating) might help.

Comment: I was having the same problem with an issue ticket (jira) reference of the format `ORG-N`. Also, this is (at least) the second time I've had a similar issue, because I can see I've already upvoted the question, answer and @MartinTournoij 's helpful link.