# Ctrl-A and Ctrl-X doing the opposite of what they should

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

I had the following piece of Markdown text that I wanted to edit:

```
 * 2-6 for a moka pot
 * 7-10 for a drip machine
 * 5-12 for a pour-over
```

When I had the cursor over the number `6` in the first bullet point, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> should “*Add* `[count]` to the number or alphabetic character at or after the cursor”. Instead of giving `7`, Vim decreased the number from `6` to `5`. When I tried to decrease the number using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, it incremented instead. It was like both commands were doing the opposite of what they should.

I checked to see if some key-mapping was over-writing Vim’s defaults but running both `:map <C-A>` and `:nmap <C-A>` printed

> No mapping found

Ditto for `C-X`. What’s going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `set nrformats+=unsigned`.  Then vim will treat all numbers as positive and ignore the hyphen.

Comment: Wow! There’s an option for everything! The `alpha` setting could also be useful in certain circumstances. Thanks.

Comment: a workaround, if you do not want to `:set nrformats+=unsigned` is to visually select only the number and then use `Ctrl-A`/`Ctrl-X`

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that if a number is preceded by a [hyphen-minus character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) (ASCII 45, 0x2D), Vim interprets the number as being a negative integer so Vim was actually adding `+1` to `-6`, giving `-5`.

The solution was to replace the hyphens with en dashes to represent the [range of values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Ranges_of_values):

```
 * 2–6 for a moka pot
 * 7–10 for a drip machine
 * 5–12 for a pour-over
```

Note: Jason Diamond’s [UniCycle plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1384) makes it easy to replace ASCII characters with typographically appropriate Unicode characters.

Comment: Only after typing out and posting both question and answer, I discovered https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5219/1608  I figured I'd keep this here as my problem was slighly different and I had come up with a solution that worked with Vim (but wouldn't work with dates.